# How to set enter key press for a HTML tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add an enter key press after the `alert(get_approve_2.innerHTML);` as the code below.

This means that every time the alert runs, the enter key press then starts after the alert's popup.

```
$(get_status1).change(function(){ // Get value of Status 1
                //alert($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
                var value = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
                var get_approve_2 = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_ee431d81_6c29_4b13_a29e_884f483a4e68_ff171_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_upLevelDiv");

                if (value == "Approve"){
                    var name_approve_2 = "Receptionist";
                    get_approve_2.innerHTML = name_approve_2;
                    alert(get_approve_2.innerHTML);
                    // Enter key press goes here
                }

                else{
                    //alert("Reject");
                    get_approve_2.innerHTML = " ";
                }
            });
```

I have tried with this but I don't know how it can be run automatically or be trigged

```
function runScript(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var tb = document.getElementById("scriptBox");
    eval(tb.value);
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to physically simulate pressing `enter`? Are you just trying to run a function after the alert?

Comment: **@Luxelin**: That's it but I don't know how it can be run automatically or be trigged.

Comment: **@samitha**: I have tried that but it seems not working for me at all..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery.You can use which event on key code 13 for the enter key

```
// Enter key press goes here

$('Your selector').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

As you said if you want to automatically be trigged

```
function runScript(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var tb = document.getElementById("scriptBox");
    eval(tb.value);
    return false;
}
}
```

Add your function there

```
            if (value == "Approve"){
                var name_approve_2 = "Receptionist";
                get_approve_2.innerHTML = name_approve_2;
                alert(get_approve_2.innerHTML);
                // Enter key press goes here
                  runScript(13); //run your function there 
            }
```

Comment: Runscript should probably accept an int and not event

Comment: **@samitha**: It seems not working for me at all.. **@Artjom B**: Please let me know what you mean?